# Is there a mathematical way to determine a solution for puzzle games?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle, combinatorial-geometry

Or more specifically, a mathematical way to determine HOW to solve a puzzle game.

Take a look at this screenshot of a puzzle game "The Talos Principle."

[image]

As you can see, the purpose of this mini-puzzle is to fill in the rectangle with Tetris blocks. I've struggled through some of them, but I managed to brute force my way through, while always having in mind "there's gotta be an easier way to solve these problems."

Is there any developed... stuff? to solve these puzzles?

Comment: There are some more questions I wanted to ask, but it would've added too much to the question. Such as: if you look at the screenshot, there's a solution present. With a given set of blocks, and given dimension of the rectangle, is that solution unique?

Comment: A computer could just do a brute force search for all solutions. I have a screensaver on an old unix machine that does precisely this ;-)

Comment: @slider but couldn't any puzzle be solved with brute force?

Comment: This kind of puzzle is discussed to some extent in *Winning Ways for Your Mathematical Plays*.

Comment: You can't solve a complicated puzzle like chess with brute force -- it would take too much time and space. But you can solve this one.

Comment: I suspect that this is an NP complete problem meaning that if you were to write a computer program for solving the puzzle, it would have to try a combinatorial number of arrangements in order to guarantee a solution.  However, there may be heuristics based on the shapes of the pieces.  We used to have "Soma Cubes" when I was a kid which are 3-D pieces that can the arranged to make various 3-D shapes.

Comment: This is a polyomino packing problem, which can be set up as an [exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover). One fast algorithm for handling exact cover problems is Donald Knuth’s [Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X). Knuth devotes a portion of Section 7.2.2.1 in _The Art of Computer Programming_, volume 4B, to the topic of using computers to solve such polyomino packing problems efficiently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling comes up with the paper

- Erik D. Demaine and Martin L. Demaine. *Jigsaw Puzzles, Edge Matching, and Polyomino Packing: Connections and Complexity*. Graph. Comb. 23, 1 (February 2007), 195-208.

where corollary 3 states that

> It is NP-complete to decide whether $n$ given polyomino pieces, each
>   fitting within an $\Theta(\log n) \times \Theta(\log n)$ rectangle, can be
>   exactly packed into a specified square box whose area equals the total
>   area of the pieces.

This doesn't *quite* say that there's not going to be any simple answer to your question, but it's fairly close to saying that.

The paper is available at

http://erikdemaine.org/papers/Jigsaw_GC/paper.pdf

if you're interested.